# How to save image with graphics object (lines ) in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure

I need to save an image with lines on it.
But I can't achieve save image with lines on it. 
I displayed image with lines and text (I use `insertText()`).
I saved only image and text.

Could anyone help me ?

```
Idisp = getimage(gca);
imwrite(Idisp, 'test.png');
```

I would appreciate any help.
[image]

Comment: Do you want to save the entire figure?  What about using `saveas`?

Comment: I want to save an image with two lines and text

Comment: Why don't you just show the image, put the two lines and text in the image, then save the entire image with `saveas`?  I don't understand your question.

Comment: When I use saveas(gcf, filename,'png'). It saves me all with gui.

Comment: It is like a screenshot but I need only image with lines and text

Comment: It should only save the contents of the figure, not the entire GUI.  I still don't understand your question.  Please show us an example image and manually point to what you want saved.  It isn't a fluke where when you're dealing with images, you need to show an image of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Check the following: `I = imread('peppers.png');J = insertText(I, [256, 192], 'Agata', 'AnchorPoint', 'Center', 'FontSize', 72);imwrite(J, 'Agata.png');`

Comment: Yes, It works with text insertText I have already tried. But I have a Problem to save line on the Image.